# Inserting (Appending) text on the top of a UITextView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, append, uitextview

I have a UITextView where I insert text using:

```
MyUITextView.insertText(my_string_to_be_inserted)
```

[image]

it works fine but it appends text to the bottom of the UITextView.

Is there any way to add text on the top (like a stack) where the last added text will be always on the top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the snippet below.

```
if let position = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.beginningOfDocument) {
   textView.replace(position, withText: "Your text goes here")
}
```

Refer the api [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614558-replace).

Comment: It worked fine.

Would you mind explaining how this snippet works, please?

Thanks

Comment: .replace function will replace the content in the provided text range with the string given. In your case the text range to be replaced is 0. We obtained that text range from textview using textrange function by giving both from and to as beginningOfDocument ( since the range we need is zero ). Hope it is clear. If you find the answer helpful you can accept and upvote it so that it could help others too. Cheers.